# Generate weeks from column with dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a large dataset  which contains a date column that covers  from the year 2019. Now I do want to generate number of weeks on a separate column that are contained in those dates.

Here is how the date column looks like:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'date': ['2019-09-10', 'NaN', '2019-10-07', '2019-11-04', '2019-11-28',
       '2019-12-02', '2020-01-24', '2020-01-29', '2020-02-05',
       '2020-02-12', '2020-02-14', '2020-02-24', '2020-03-11',
       '2020-03-16', '2020-03-17', '2020-03-18', '2021-09-14',
       '2021-09-30', '2021-10-07', '2021-10-08', '2021-10-12',
       '2021-10-14', '2021-10-15', '2021-10-19', '2021-10-21',
       '2021-10-26', '2021-10-28', '2021-10-29', '2021-11-02',
       '2021-11-15', '2021-11-16', '2021-12-01', '2021-12-07',
       '2021-12-09', '2021-12-10', '2021-12-14', '2021-12-15',
       '2022-01-13', '2022-01-14', '2022-01-21', '2022-01-24',
       '2022-01-25', '2022-01-27', '2022-01-31', '2022-02-01',
       '2022-02-10', '2022-02-11', '2022-02-16', '2022-02-24']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now as from the first day this data was collected, I want to count 7 days using the date column and create a week out it. an example if the first week contains the 7 dates, I create a column and call it week one. I want to do the same process until the last week the data was collected.

Maybe it will be a good idea to organize the dates in order as from the first date to current one.

I have tried this but its not generating weeks in order, it actually has repetitive weeks.

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce').dt.week
```

My intention is, as from the first date the date was collected, count 7 days and store that as week one then continue incrementally until the last week say week number 66.

Here is the expected column of weeks created from the date column

```
import pandas as pd

week_df = {'weeks': ['1', '2', "3", "5", '6']}

df_weeks = pd.DataFrame(week_df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC use:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['week'] = df['date'].sub(df['date'].iat[0]).dt.days // 7 + 1
print (df.head(10))
        date  week
0 2019-09-10   1.0
1        NaT   NaN
2 2019-10-07   4.0
3 2019-11-04   8.0
4 2019-11-28  12.0
5 2019-12-02  12.0
6 2020-01-24  20.0
7 2020-01-29  21.0
8 2020-02-05  22.0
9 2020-02-12  23.0
```

Comment: Worked like magic. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have more than 66 weeks here, so either you want the real week count since the beginning or you want a dummy week rank. See below for both solutions:

```
# convert to week period
s = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.to_period('W')

# get real week number
df['week'] = s.sub(s.iloc[0]).dropna().apply(lambda x: x.n).add(1)

# get dummy week rank
df['week2'] = s.rank(method='dense')
```

output:

```
          date   week  week2
0   2019-09-10    1.0    1.0
1          NaN    NaN    NaN
2   2019-10-07    5.0    2.0
3   2019-11-04    9.0    3.0
4   2019-11-28   12.0    4.0
5   2019-12-02   13.0    5.0
6   2020-01-24   20.0    6.0
7   2020-01-29   21.0    7.0
8   2020-02-05   22.0    8.0
9   2020-02-12   23.0    9.0
10  2020-02-14   23.0    9.0
11  2020-02-24   25.0   10.0
12  2020-03-11   27.0   11.0
13  2020-03-16   28.0   12.0
14  2020-03-17   28.0   12.0
15  2020-03-18   28.0   12.0
16  2021-09-14  106.0   13.0
17  2021-09-30  108.0   14.0
18  2021-10-07  109.0   15.0
19  2021-10-08  109.0   15.0
...
42  2022-01-27  125.0   26.0
43  2022-01-31  126.0   27.0
44  2022-02-01  126.0   27.0
45  2022-02-10  127.0   28.0
46  2022-02-11  127.0   28.0
47  2022-02-16  128.0   29.0
48  2022-02-24  129.0   30.0
```